# How to callback function in set timeout node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I have to call a function with the callback in set timeout for that I have written code like this

```
getData(a, b, function(err, rlt) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        // call next function after 35 seconds 
        settimeout(getData(c, d, function(err, rlt) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                // call next function after 10 seconds
                settimeout(getData(x, y, function(err, rlt) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    } else {
                        console.log(rlt);
                    }
                }), 10000);
            }
        }), 35000)
    }
});


function getData(parms1, parms2;, callback) {
    return callback(null, parms1 + parms2);
}
```

I have written code similar to this but my problem is that set timeout not working its execute function immediately not wait for 35 seconds and 10 seconds.

I don't know what wrong I am doing and if you know any better way to do please help me.

Comment: function getData(parms1, parms2;, callback) {
    return parms1 + parms2;
}

is this correct?

Comment: @NullPointer sorry my bad i forgot to put callback over there i just updated my question

Comment: Just curious... have you considered using `Promise` or `async await` instead of `setTimeout`? The code you have shared is fragile and a good example of callback hell.

Comment: I know to do all these thing with async but it want to execute other function after sometime not immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wrap your calls to getData in an anonymous function, e.g. `setTimeout(function(){ getData(x, y, …) }, 1000)`.

Comment: thax its worked..but if konw better way please tell me i want to avoid this callback hell

Comment: Maybe [Taming Timeouts with a Promise](https://www.theguardian.com/info/developer-blog/2014/dec/10/taming-timeouts-with-a-promise) is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the correct syntax for `setTimeout`.Your `method` should be always as a first argument of  `setTimeout` function

```
setTimeout(function(){myMethod(parameter);},3000);
```

Full Reference: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/Node.js_Tutorial/0270__Node.js_setTimeout_setInterval.htm

Comment: thax its worked..but if konw better way please tell me i want to avoid this callback hell

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss spell of settimeout(**setTimeout**) Try this code:

```
 var callback = function (err, res) {
        if(err){
           console.log (err);
        }else{
              setTimeout(function() {
                 callback()
                 console.log ("start callback function");
                 }, 10000)
        }
    };
```